# Both: Key Repeat & Press and Hold

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is it possible to use **both** the Key Repeat & the Press and Hold functionality in OS X Mavericks? How?

I write in English, French and German on a Macbook's US keyboard often. I really like the Press and Hold accent popups, but I also need the Key Repeat functionality to work decently with iTerm2, ssh, vim, sublime and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every app you want key repeat to work in, run

```
defaults write <bundle-ID> ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

<sup>…then restart the app.</sup>